# Browser vs Context in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

In learning Playwright, I've learned about browser vs context (or `browserContext` according to playwright).
From my understanding, Browser represents an actual browser instance (Chrome/Firefox/etc..) whereas Browser Context is an isolated instance that multiple "Pages" are ran on, (From my understanding a Page is literally a tab/page representation.

So I understand Browser, and Page.......but im a little bit confused at what "Context" actually is.

I've read that this is what a "Worker" shares (Still unsure of what exactly a "worker" is for playwright, but that's not the point of this post).

That being said, I have a few questions:

1. What exactly is a Browser Context in a easy to explain way. I'm assuming it's close to what selenium considers a "session"?
2. Why if a "page" represents an actual tab, do we need a new browserContext when opening a new tab within a test?
3. Should browser sessions/context be shared across tests? I know `Playwright test` handles this automatically....but is a browser and context opened and closed after/before every single test?
4. When using Page Object Model: Should we be passing in an actual page or context?

As a side question: Is there any benefit to NOT using `Playwright test` and opening/closing browser/context ourselves? I understand sometimes there is some benefit in complicated cases.....but right now im not seeing them.

Comment: Please narrow the post down to a single question. Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific, _single_ question. Revise your post to match.